# Java rearrange array based on element number

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is my array:

```
int[] myArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

Let's say I want to move myArray[3] (it could be any element) and myArray[6] (same with this one) to the front of the array while rearranging the back, how can I do this? Example:

This:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Into this:

```
{3, 6, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: @ Conner: Try to use linked list concept for this problem.Rearranging the array will take lot of time and space complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To move index `x` to the front, you need to:

- Remember what's at index `x`
- Copy everything from `0` to `x - 1` up one index, e.g. with `System.arrayCopy`
- Set the value at index `0` to be the value you remembered in the first step

For example:

```
public void moveToHead(int[] values, int index)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    int value = values[index];
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, values, 1, index - 1);
    values[0] = value;
}
```

Note that `System.arraycopy` handles the copying appropriately:

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination array.

Your original example mentioned two elements - while you *could* potentially do all of this more efficiently knowing both elements in advance, it would be far, far simpler to model this as two `moveToHead` calls. You need to take care about the ordering - for example, if you want to move index `6` to the head first, you'll need to then move index 4 rather than index 3, to take account of the first move.

Comment: @ConnerRuhl: I've provided a method to do the move - now you just need to call it with appropriate levels of care. (See my last paragraph.)

Comment: When I try this with objects it overrides objects with references

Comment: @ConnerRuhl: You'll need to provide more details than that - such as a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @ConnerRuhl: Well you can never have an array of objects - you can only have an array of references. But then yes, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution may be to transform your array into a list thanks to the [asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method and simply use the [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) and [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) methods:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
myList.add(myList.remove(myIndex));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work - the list you get from `Arrays.asList` allows neither `add` nor `remove`. Replace it with `new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray))` and it should work, though.

Comment: I was wondering about that but forgot to test it. Thanks for the comment, the answer is corrected :)